# Variable transformation Birnbaum-Saunders distribution

Tags: r, distributions

I am having some trouble with a textbook problem.

I have to show that if T ∼ BS(α, β) then 1/T∼ BS(α, 1/β) How should I do it?

I already find the way to show that T is [Birnbaum-Saunders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birnbaum%E2%80%93Saunders_distribution) distributed by doing a transformation
of the R.V.

[image]

then I find out that Z is a standard normal random variable so it was easy to find the mean and the Variance.

Now I don't know how to show that 1/T is also Birnbaum-Saunders distributed, I tried to replace 1/T and 1/B in the pdf, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here the PDF and the CDF of the Birnbaum-Saunders

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the [tag:self-study] tag & read 
[its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints: Use the fact that for a probability distribution $X$ with strictly positive support (which the Birnbaum-Saunders distribution is), it is relatively easy to find the distribution of $Y=1/X$. Let $F_{X}(x)$ be the cumulative distribution function (cdf) of $X$. Then, the cdf of $Y$, $F_{Y}(y)$ is:
$$
F_{Y}(y) = \mathbb{P}(1/X\leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X\geq 1/y) = 1 - F_{X}(1/y)
$$

Another useful fact is $1-\Phi(x)= \Phi(-x)$. So you're left to show that $1-F_{X}(1/y;\ \alpha, \beta) = F_{X}(y;\ \alpha, 1/\beta)$.